# How to direct an app to use a specific Java version?

Tags: java, macos

I got an Java application that **does** run under Java 1.8 without problems when I start its JAR directly.
However on my Mac the JAR is wrapped within an app that demands me to install Java 1.6 -- which I really do not want to do!

So I'm searching the point within the app package where I could configure that my App shall use the installed Java 1.8

Changing property `InfoDictionary version` within `Contents/Info.plist` to 8.0 will not help.

Is this possible at all or do I need to build a complete new App Package?
In case of the later, which tool would be best to do this for a bunch of applications?

Comment: Is the app a Java application on its own, or is it called Tom within another app? If it's a Java app on its own, you can point a specific Java version at it, otherwise you'll need to specify a global Java version any time you want to open that app.

Comment: @agentroadkill: Originally it's an application of its own, being deployed as a JAR file on every other platform. For MacOS it is packaged within an APP package. If you select "show package content" in it you will find some meta data, Info.plist and the JAR itself. I can start this JAR directly though.

Comment: @agentroadkill: So, could you please elaborate a bit on how to specify my Java version to all the apps?

Comment: [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/490425/how-do-i-switch-between-java-7-and-java-6-on-os-x-10-8-2) is the SuperUser post specifying what you're looking to do. I'll elaborate more in an answer below.

Comment: I think this answer may complete this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15379462/335478

Comment: that describes how to deploy an app with a built-in JRE. It was my understanding you had an application which had external Java dependencies you were attempting to run. If you were attempting to build an app, I apologize for the misunderstanding; StackExchange is the proper forum for that sort of question.

Comment: No, you did not get it wrong. I don't want to build an app, but to get an existing app running. However the answer describes that fumbling with Info.plist cannot work, as this is an apple mechanism. And Oracle will use a different stub and packaging. It also mentions that `Jar Bundler` that could be used to re-pack my JARs would always use the apple JRE. I'm sure that there is an utility out there to create an APP package from JARs using Oracle's mechanism.

Comment: If that's all you want to do, the easiest thing may be to simply write a quick script in Automator, then build an app from Automator with all the decencies (your .jar and the JRE) bundled in.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to a post on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/490425/how-do-i-switch-between-java-7-and-java-6-on-os-x-10-8-2), this appears to be fairly straightforward. It appears that different Java versions can be called from Apple's own JRE:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6.0 --exec <Java command>
```

My understanding is that this doesn't actually provide a different JRE, but simply causes the installed JRE to identify itself as the called version, and implements any minor differences between versions. Others should definitely correct me if this is not the case.

For your purposes, this would be

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6.0 --exec java -jar <yourJarHere>.jar
```

The above linked post also points out that you can edit the file called /Applications/yourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/yourApp to use the correct command so you don't need to re-type that or remember every time.

All this courtesy [Geff](https://superuser.com/users/167435/geff)

Comment: All it does is run the java defined with the -v parameter

Comment: Right-the issue was that the app wanted a different version of the JRE. This causes the Apple-supplied JRE to identify itself as the required one, and provides the expected functions of that Java version

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Oracle could have fixed this. But didn't ...

So I got it working now doing this:
(All credits go to: https://oliverdowling.com.au/2014/03/28/java-se-8-on-mac-os-x)

I assume you got the latest JDK installed (currently 1.8.0_60, please adjust this in future)

#### Change content of Info.plist:

Open Terminal and issue this command

```
sudo nano /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Info.plist
```

Look for key `JVMCapabilities` and change it to this:

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>CommandLine</string>
    <string>JNI</string>
    <string>BundledApp</string>
</array>
```

#### Add a symlink for `libjvm.dylib` and `libserver.dylib`:

Open Terminal and issue these two commands:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
```

Comment: What does this chnage do?

Comment: @Mark This change allows the JVM to be run not only from the command line, but also the Java Native Interface and bundled apps. However, you may find that it will still be unable to find `libjvm.dylib` and `libserver.dylib` which is fixed with the symlinks.

Comment: this is a great answer but how do you apply this to JRE instead of a JDK? I found the equivalent for the symlinking under `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/` but there is no Info.plist that contains a `JVMCapabilities` entry.

Answer (score 3):

This might help jump-start finding an answer. Recalling that PyCharm.app does something similar, here is an extract from the applications `Info.plist` file (watch the …snip… lines in there):

```
…snip…
<key>JVMOptions</key>
<dict>
  …snip…
  <key>JVMVersion</key>
  <!-- string>1.6*,1.7+</string -->
  <string>1.7+</string>
  …snip…
</dict>
…snip…
```

Also, the PaperCut Client application (PCClient) uses some simliar items in its `Info.plist`:

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    …snip…
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>JavaAppLauncher</string>
    <key>JVMRuntime</key>
    <string>jre</string>
    <key>JVMMainClassName</key>
    <string>biz.papercut.pcng.client.uit.UserClient</string>
    <key>JVMOptions</key>
    <array>
      <string>-Dclient.home=$APP_ROOT/Contents/Resources/</string>
      <string>-Dcom.apple.macos.useScreenMenuBar=true</string>
      <string>-Xmx256m</string>
      <!-- Workaround since the icon parameter for bundleapp doesn't work -->
      <string>-Xdock:icon=$APP_ROOT/Contents/Resources/client-icon.icns</string>
    </array>
    <key>JVMArguments</key>
    <array/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Again, these are parts of different `Info.plist` files so they might not work as straight copy-and-paste. However, both apps **work** on OS X, so these keys/values might help you narrow down to a working solution.

Both apps seem to have a slightly different way of doing things. PCClient.app appears to include it's own version of Java, whereas PyCharm relies on what’s installed on OS X.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the place where I thought one should be able to state the minimal JRE required... However, none of these settings had an effect. I still get a dialog asking to install JRE 1.6. I think it also depends on the JavaAppLauncher that is actually started up, which will in turn ask for a JRE 1.6

Answer (score 0):

for details, please check/read this section "OPTIONAL / EXTRA : Setup Specific Java ENV-VAR" (this section is in bottomside) of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62874205/3553808), pls also see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/396025/133434) answer.

Summary:

1. Obtain Legacy Java 8 (JDK, 1.8, it includes JRE) binary (that is optimized for macOS) (and it also includes Src-code), from Oracle [site](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html) & install it, (Oracle based Java is free only-for Personal usage, not-free for Commercial usage & not-free if you want to distribute JRE ) . ( [OpenJDK](https://jdk.java.net/archive/) based Legacy Java 8 ([1.8](https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/)) Src-code is available in `OpenJDK.java.net` site, for those, who want to compile it & build their own binary . OpenJDK (includes JRE) v9 (1.9) & above are available as macOS optimized binary form in [OpenJDK](https://jdk.java.net/archive/) archive-site/page . OpenJDK based Java is free for any Commercial usage & also free for Personal usage. )
2. Setup these specific ENV VARs: JAVA_HOME & PATH, only for a specific App, before running it, by using a shell script:
   ( do not type the word `'cmd:'`, when you copy/type a command from here )

- Run this command-set to create a shell-script file with a header line:
  `cmd:  sb='#!/bin/bash' ; echo "$sb" > ~/java-based-APP-name.sh ; unset sb;`
  ( change the `"java-based-APP-name"` into your actual target App name )
- edit that shell script file by using `nano`:
  `cmd:  nano ~/java-based-APP-name.sh`

  - 1st line must be `#!/bin/bash` to use it as "BASH" shell script, then add below 5-lines:
    `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home --version 1.8);`
    `export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH";`
    `# $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar executableJarAppName.jar`
    `# $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp jarAppName.jar <full-path-of-main-class>`
    `"/Applications/java-based-APP-name.app/Contents/MacOS/java-based-APP-name"`
- Save `"~/java-based-APP-name.sh"` & exit out from nano . ( [Nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/cheatsheet.html) )
  ( Note: if a macOS app's name is `"My MacApp.app"`, then it must have an executable file with same name here: `"My MacApp.app/Contents/MacOS/My MacApp"` . So above example script is using that example executable )
- And set 'execute' permission bit: `cmd:  chmod +x ~/java-based-APP-name.sh`

3. Now you can run the App by using the shell-script: `cmd:  ~/java-based-APP-name.sh`
   ( that App will have access to Java 8 (1.8) which you've installed, & which you've specified in the shell script . You can also create a shortcut/link for that shell-script & place the link inside the `/Applications` , so that you can see an Icon & just click that to run the target App. )